# How does a sigmoid neuron act like a perceptron in this scenario?

Tags: neural-networks, perceptron, sigmoid

I have been reading Michael Nielsen’s book online on his website at http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html. I am struggling to understand the second exercise:
[image]

When c approaches infinity, wouldn’t make the sigmoid function always output a value close to 1 whereas a perceptron can output 0 or 1.

Let me know if I am missing something or maybe if someone can rephrase the question in a clearer way.

Comment: Please don't post text as pictures, rather copy paste referring to the source.

Answer (score 1):

> When c approaches infinity, wouldn’t make the sigmoid function always
> output a value close to 1 whereas a perceptron can output 0 or 1.

This is true only when the original value was positive.

$e^{-cx}$ coverges to $0$ (and $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-cx}}$ converges to $1$) as $c$ approaches infinity only when $x$ is positive. If x is negative, $e^{-cx}$ diverges to infinity and thus $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-cx}}$ converges to $0$.

Thus, the sigmoid function behaves like a step function as $c$ approaches infinity.